# Java split "a"."b"."c" using regular expression

Tags: java, regex, split

I have string: "a.aa"."bb.b"."ccc." and need to split it into values:

a.aa
bb.b
ccc.

How can I do that?

I have tried with:

```
String str = "\"a.aa\".\"bb.b\".\"ccc.\"";
System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(st‌​r.split("[\"\"]")));
```

but it gives response:

```
[, a.aa, ., bb.b, ., ccc.]
```

and I expect response like this

```
[a.aa, bb.b, ccc.]
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. What have you tried? Show us your attempts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do you need it like:

```
String str =  "\"a.aa\".\"bb.b\".\"ccc.\"";

String[] strSplited = str.substring(1,str.length() - 1).split("\".\"");
```

Comment: um i have a feeling that the string looks like '"a.aa"."bb.b"."ccc."' and that this is a word processor homework

Comment: But strSplited[0] and strSplited[last] contains `"a.aa` and `ccc."` respectively.

Comment: @VimalBera no they aren't... i mean depend on how the input looks like

Comment: @user2725370 look at my edit, and you can edit the question you know, you don't have to write the code in a comment

Comment: It does the job. Thank you very much!

Comment: @user2725370 little advise: don't post your code in comments because it is hard to read. Also dont post it under some answer because not many people will see it, but instead include it to your original question with edit option under it.

Comment: Made some correction to question. Hope now it's more understandable.

Comment: @user2725370 Now it is better. I also improved it a little :)

Comment: Thank Pshemo, now it looks really beautiful.

Comment: @user2725370 no problem :) btw you dont need to use `<br>` in your queston, two spaces and new line mark (enter) will do the trick. Also use `{}` key from post editor to make your code look as it looks now.

Comment: @NoIdeaForName ofcoz `str.length()`, not `str.Size()`